# Is there a way to see the "expanded props" of a React functional component in Visual Studio Code when using predefined types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I noticed that when defining React components this way:

```
type LogInScreenProps = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean
  redirectTo?: string
}

export const LogInScreen: React.FC<LogInScreenProps> = ({ isAuthenticated, redirectTo }) => { ...
```

When using the component, VSCode only shows you the following when you hover on `LogInScreen`:

```
(alias) const LogInScreen: FC<LogInScreenProps>
import LogInScreen
```

Is there a way to get the same result as when adding the type inline like this:

```
export const LogInScreen: React.FC<{
  isAuthenticated: boolean
  redirectTo?: string
}> = ({ isAuthenticated, redirectTo }) => {
```

Showing this when implementing:

```
(alias) const LogInScreen: FC<{
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    redirectTo?: string | undefined;
}>
import LogInScreen
```

Comment: Doesn't it already do that? It does in the playground at least: https://tsplay.dev/Nle1Xm

Comment: It even does in VSCode, at least in https://vscode.dev... I'm not able to reproduce this.

Comment: Oh my god I just realized I misread your question

Comment: Ok, I don't think there is a way, but you could overwrite `FC` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo5jeN) with module augmentation (don't mind the error, shouldn't occur when you use it in a project).

Comment: Wow ok, I presume this is some sort of generic `Expand` we could use for anything? Pretty creative - do you want to post the answer? I also thought about using TSDoc but your solution seems less hacky

Comment: "Just about anything" - as long as you have the cases covered. Also, it doesn't give you any freedoms in choosing what to expand; it just expands everything it cans, which may be a headache if the type to expand is quite large.

Comment: yeah since it overrides `FC`, unless you would start adding custom types just do expand certain props, but then it would become pretty cumbersome to manage - maybe this is the type of problem that could be better fixed with a VSCode plugin just for the props use case?

Comment: Don't forget to post your answer if you want credit - its a pretty good one by the one - maybe others would benefit as well

Comment: By the way, I think `Expand` is not ready for production :) https://tsplay.dev/mLyoZW

Comment: Well... I don't think it possible to list out all the cases now is it  I'll make sure the answer works locally later since I don't have a true environment to test it on right now.